# Rails 4.1 scope method with relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 4.1 and trying to setup a scope method that seems like it should be easy, but I can't seem to get figured out.

The high-level data models are:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :actions, through: :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :request
  belongs_to :action
end

class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum usertype: { isnormal: 0, isadmin: 1 }
end
```

For our app, a `Request` is denoted as an administrative request if any of its associated actions' `usertype` is set to `isadmin`.

I'm trying to setup a scope method (or something similar) whereby we can retrieve the administrative requests via something along the lines of `Request.admin`, and the normal requests via `Request.normal`.

I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to chain anything together to retrieve these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to come up with a solution to my question. I don't know that it's the best approach, but it is working and seems simple and straight forward enough. (And I don't know why it took so long to get at it.)

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :actions, through: :items
  scope :isadmin, -> { joins(:actions).where(actions: {usertype: Action.usertypes[:isadmin]}) }
  scope :isnormal, -> { where.not(id: isadmin.pluck(:id)) }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :actions, through: :items

  scope :with_usertype, -> (type) { joins(:actions).where(actions: {usertype: Action.usertypes[type]}) }
  scope :admin,         -> { with_usertype(:isadmin) }
  scope :normal,        -> { with_usertype(:isnormal) }
end
```

Comment: This is similar to what I've come up with before, but the `normal` scope is where I can't seem to get it correct, and perhaps I wasn't clear enough in the original question. If a request contains multiple actions and any of those actions are admin, then the request should be an admin request, and the `admin` scope works. However, the `normal` scope method also picks up these same admin requests if any of its actions `normal`.

Comment: Example: a request that contains two actions (through items), the first action is admin, and the second action is normal. Both the `admin` scope method and the `normal` scope method pick up this request, but I'm looking to limit it to just the `admin` scope method retrieving it, and the `normal` scope method leave it since it contains an admin action.